# For fingerprint use in api<28 ...what should i use...Fingerprint Manager otlr BiometricPrompt?

Tags: android

I tried to add biometric prompt but that's not working
It shows that BiometricPrompt can't be instantiated...because its not public class.
I m using java in android studio

Comment: This is unanswerable since you haven't show us the relevant code and build scripts.

Comment: Post your code pls

Answer (score 0):

Declare permission in Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
```

Comment: Declared also added dependency...yet no effect